# fill a listview with textformfield

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Basically i want to fill Listview with a Textformfield. if anyone could guide me through that

### git link for full code

github.com/Nyctophilus/Thoth_Script
i've added some changes my main issue now all tiles in the listview taking the same value. it don't read my setState change! and the FAB too

### List Code

```
  TextEditingController Tcon = TextEditingController();

  Widget _list(context, index) {
    if (index > 0) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: index,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text('Task: ${index + 1}  $Tcon'),
          );
        },
      );
    } else {
      return ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        children: const <Widget>[
          Text("Add task..."),
        ],
      );
    }
  }
```

### Text field Code

```
        child: TextField(
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          controller: Tcon,
          onSubmitted: (value) {
            setState(() {
              Tcon.text = value;
              index++;
            });
          },
        ),
```

[image: This is what's looks like now]

Comment: `Listview with a Textformfield.` do you mean like a giant text form field, or do you want multiple  dynamic text fields

Comment: it's like a Text Field for user to input text , so i take it to display on a listView Dynamically ,yea

Comment: Can you please describe in more detail what you are trying to make? or where do you need help?

Comment: you want to create dynamic List<TextFormField>?

Comment: please share the github link for me to help you better. And if i understand you correctly you want to add new task to the listView when you press the floating button and textFormField will update the textFormController and save it to the listview

Comment: @DishankJindal https://github.com/Nyctophilus/Thoth_Script
yeah you understand me perfectly. my main issue now all tiles in the listview taking the same value. it don't read my setState change! and the FAB too

Comment: I just fixed your issue. You were basically not using the textEditingcontroller properly. check your github i sent you the fix. just approve the pull request and run on yout device.

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping your textfield in a Container

```
Container(
            width: 650,
            height: 45,
            child: TextField(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              controller: Tcon,
              onSubmitted: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  Tcon.text = value;
                  index++;
                });
              },
            ),
      ),
```

Comment: i did try that and didn't work. the error in the size of the listview not the textfield.. oh i wrap the listview with Expanded and it showed up. it was alignment prob! ><

Answer (score 0):

Tcon is a single text editing controller which you are assigning to all textfields in the list. You have to create List and assign each of its child to each textfield so every textfield will have its own controller.